# SonarQube / AngularJS - How to I get SonarQube up and running to get my Angular project integrated / analyzed?

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I have a front end project (AngularJS - not latest version) and want to analyze the code with SonarQube.

Here is what I did so far.

1)  Grabbed my project from GitHub and cloned to desktop.

2)  Downloaded SonarQube-6.5 and extracted to desktop.

3)  Opened sonarqube-6.5\extensions\plugins (in my extracted directory) and pasted a front end plugin (downloaded from https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-plugin)

4)  Created sonar-project.properties in my web directory of my project

Contents

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=project-name
sonar.projectName=project name
sonar.projectVersion=0.1

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src/app

# exclude some files and folders (typically dependencies)
sonar.exclusions=bower_components/**/*, node_modules/**/*

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Then I ran the following in command line.

> cd project root dir
>
> "c:\\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe"
>   begin /k:"orag.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild"
>   /n:"CMNHMobile-nextrelease" /v:"1.0" c:\pathto ms build\MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
>   "c:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe"
>   end

After these steps I do not see any project listed in my localhost:9000 (SonarQube)

What can I do to show the project for analysis?

Comment: Use of the following plugin (SonarJS) helped resolve my confusion and begin analysis - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of the following plugin (SonarJS) helped resolve my confusion and begin analysis - docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS

Answer (score 1):

This is SonarJS project github home where you can get the latest updates: https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS

Comment: Thank you Sam, I neglected to provide direct link to the actual plugin I found.  I have awarded you a point for taking the time to answer my question.